# Power Bi Filtering Data

Tags: report, powerbi, hierarchical-data

I am new to Power Bi. Currently, I am trying to see if it will be the right fit. I am trying to filter data down through three different levels:
-Department 
  -Group
    -Item

I was trying to use multiple filters but this is not working.

[image]

Comment: I don't understand your question. What isn't working?

Comment: I am trying to find a way to filter down to the item level on the same chart I filter down to the group level and department level.

Comment: So, you want a [Hierarchy Slicer](https://appsource.microsoft.com/en-us/product/power-bi-visuals/WA104380820)?

Comment: Perfect that works for what I need it to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [Hierarch Slicer](https://appsource.microsoft.com/en-us/product/power-bi-visuals/WA104380820) visual allows you to filter data at different levels.

Here's an example from the linked page:

[image: Example]